# What is the best way to fix this garage floor?

Tags: floor, garage

I need an educated opinion about how to fix the garage floor shown below. I need the surface to be level and even. As you can see I have two items, a table saw and and work bench that have adjustable casters or legs. Every time when I move them into position to work (usually they sit on the sides of the room) I have to adjust the legs to bring the table top level with the table saw top.

[image]

[image]

Comment: An epoxy coat would be my initial thought

Comment: Your garage should be slightly sloped towards the driveway so that water does not pool.

Comment: @Ghost: I was under the impression that an epoxy coat needs a smooth surface and it does not solve the irregularities of the supporting surface (floor) Am I wrong?

Comment: There is prep work involved and it won't fix all the issues on it's own. http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/how-to/intro/0,,20174654,00.html

Comment: I don't think that I need the epoxy stuff. I don't need the everything aligned down to millimeters, I just need to get rid of the roughness of the surface and hide the cracks

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, the ancient quest for flatness.

You could put down a mortar bed, but it will degrade over time if it is unsurfaced.

In general, putting good concrete over bad concrete doesn't work. Trying to flatten just one area of a garage will not be easy. One possible procedure would be to get a jack hammer and remove about 1 to 2 inches of concrete everywhere you want to be flat. Then get down on your hand and knees with a level and chisel it all out so it is pretty smooth and level. Then pour new concrete into the draft, or better yet get an experienced paver to do it. Making really smooth flat concrete surfaces takes a lot of skill.

Also, you could do all that, and whatever caused the crack in the first place will crack your new concrete.

Comment: I am startingto believe that two 2x4x10 aligned perfectly under the legs of both tables will fix the problem quicker and simpler than anything else